# Hibernate TypedQuery fails after upgrade to version 5 if it ends with )

Tags: java, hibernate

We are trying to upgrade hibernate from 4.3.5 to hibernate 5.4.0 during which we encountered an error for a typed query that worked earlier.

```
entityManager.createQuery("select u from " + GenericConnection.class.getName() + " u where u.id = :uid)").setParameter("uid", connection.getId()).getResultList()
```

The typed query has an extra ')' but still it worked well earlier. Post upgrade it fails Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF, found ')' near line 1, column 72

The fix is simple - remove the ')' character but since we are modifying a legacy application that has many such failures. Hence I wanted to understand if this was a intentional fix from the hibernate team and whether it has any side-effects. A reference to an hibernate jira issue would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: its malformed no mather what .

Comment: Any update on this?